# run logstash-forwarder in untrusted network-environment

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I want to figure out a safe way to run logstash-forwarder respectively logstash with the lumberjack-input in an untrusted network-environment.

As far as I understand, the SSL-certificate ensures an encrypted connection between client and server und authenticates the server for the client (as in "ok, I know this server is the real logging-server"). How can I authenticate the client for the server (as in "ok, I know this client trying to send me events is one of my machines, not someone else")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL certificates can work in bidirectional way. They can be used to authenticate the server *("ok, this server is the real logging-server")* and also the other way around *("ok, I know this client is one of my machines")*. For the second case you need to use client certificates.

Although Logstash Forwarder allows to [configure a client certificate](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder#configuring), logstash's lumberjack input [does not support client certs](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ssl-client-certs-allowed-but-lumberjack-input-doesnt-seem-to-validate-them/23946). There is an [open github issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-lumberjack/issues/31) regarding this feature.

To overcome this dilemma you can use an alternative log client and logstash's [TCP input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-tcp.html) which supports client certs. The input will look like this:

```
input {   
    tcp {
        port => 9999
        ssl_cert => "/path/to/server.crt"
        ssl_key => "/path/to/server.key"
        ssl_cacert => "/path/to/ca.crt"
        ssl_enable => true
        ssl_verify => true
    }
}
```

On the client side you can use several tools. I personally do this with [NXLog](http://nxlog.org/). A proper NXLog output config would look like this:

```
<Output logstash>
    Module  om_ssl
    Host    yourhost
    Port    9999
    CAFile  %CERTDIR%/ca.crt
    CertFile    %CERTDIR%/client.crt
    CertKeyFile %CERTDIR%/client.key
</Output>
```

Unfortunately this is just a workaround with another software but I'm afraid there is no native lumberjack solution.

Comment: Pretty annoying, but I think the feature will be in place soon.